# Migrating StorageClass from gp2 to gp3 - AWS EKS

Tags: kubectl, amazon-eks, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc, kustomize

We are using EKS and we have a stateful set that uses a storage class as volumeclaimtemplates.
Our storage classes are of type gp2 and is using the ebs.csi.aws provisioner.

We need to convert the sc's from gp2 - gp3 without any downtime. Is it possible to do it? We are using Kubectl and Kustomize , when we tried to change the type using a kustomize layer it gave me an error :
**Forbidden : Updates to parameters are forbidden**.

I also referred to this documentation which also includes steps to change the provisioner.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/migrating-amazon-eks-clusters-from-gp2-to-gp3-ebs-volumes/
I was looking to understand if we could easily change the pvc storage class type from gp2 - gp3 as we can with the AWS console and a regular volume.

Thank you